# Negative sign in calculating the equation of motion of a free particle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, action

I am working through a series of lectures and have a question on a step. Calculating the equation of motion for a free particle (beginning with  $S=-mc\int ds$), we eventually arrive at:

\begin{eqnarray}
\delta S &=& -mc \int \frac{d}{d\left( \frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau} \right)}\left(\sqrt{-\eta_{\alpha\beta}\frac{dx^{\alpha}}{d\tau}\frac{dx^{\beta}}{d\tau}}\right) \frac{d(\delta x^\mu)}{d\tau}d\tau \\
&=& -mc \int \frac{2\eta_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^{\nu}}{d\tau}}{2\sqrt{-\eta_{\alpha\beta}\frac{dx^{\alpha}}{d\tau}\frac{dx^{\beta}}{d\tau}}}\frac{d(\delta x^\mu)}{d\tau}d\tau
\end{eqnarray}

My question is why does the negative sign inside the square root not carry down to the second line? I would think that the second line should be
\begin{equation}
= -mc \int \frac{- 2\eta_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^{\nu}}{d\tau}}{2\sqrt{-\eta_{\alpha\beta}\frac{dx^{\alpha}}{d\tau}\frac{dx^{\beta}}{d\tau}}}\frac{d(\delta x^\mu)}{d\tau}d\tau
\end{equation}
since $\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{-f}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{-\frac{df}{dx}}{\sqrt{f}}$, but the notes (quoted exactly above) do not contain this negative sign. (If it matters, we are working with a metric of (-,+,+,+) signature.)

Yes, this will not matter for the free particle, but later on when calculating the equation of motion for a charged particle, this (lack of a) negative sign does become significant.

Comment: Are the lecture notes publicly available? If so please could you link to them?

Comment: Here's the link. https://esc.fnwi.uva.nl/thesis/centraal/files/f2075253302.pdf (I was mistaken, it's an undergrad thesis. Eq. 4.8 is the one mentioned above.)